# Binary tree in Scala

Tags: scala, list, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a function that will be transforming list of integers of binary tree. This is my code:

```
sealed trait btree[+A]
case class Empty extends btree[Nothing]
case class Node[+A](elem: A, left : btree[A], right : btree[A]) extends btree[A]

def list2btree(list : List[Int]) : btree[Int] = {
def insert2tree(x : Int, t : btree[Int]) : btree[Int] = {
    (x, t) match {
        case (x, Empty) => Node(x, Empty, Empty)
        case (x, Node(v, left, right)) => {
            if(v > x) Node(v, insert2tree(x, left), right)
            else if(v < x) Node(v, left, insert2tree(x,right))
            else throw new Exception("Element exsist!")
        }
    }
}

list match {
    case Nil => Empty
    case (h::t) => insert2tree(h, list2btree(t))
}
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: It is unnecessary to match with `(x, t)`. t itself is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Empty doesn't need to be a class, it should just be an object :

```
sealed trait btree[+A]
case object Empty extends btree[Nothing]
case class Node[+A](elem: A, left : btree[A], right : btree[A]) extends btree[A]
```

Then your code works (although you are adding elements in a reverse order, which may not be what you want):

```
scala> list2btree(List(6,2,3,1,4))
res0: btree[Int] = Node(4,Node(1,Empty,Node(3,Node(2,Empty,Empty),Empty)),Node(6,Empty,Empty))
```

Edit : 
On the error itself, if `Empty` is a case class, you need to had `()` after to specify you want an instance of the `Empty` class :

```
scala> case class Empty
<console>:1: warning: case classes without a parameter list have been deprecated;
use either case objects or case classes with `()' as parameter list.

scala> Empty
res0: Empty.type = Empty

scala> Empty()
res1: Empty = Empty()
```